# Accessing the window from Angular expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, window-object

According to the [developer guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) I should be able to access the browser window from inside Angular expressions with `$window`.

> Unlike JavaScript, where names default to global window properties, Angular expressions have to use $window to refer to the global window object. For example, if you want to call alert(), which is defined on window, in an expression you must use $window.alert().

However I can't seem to access `$window` from expressions evaluated with `$scope.$eval`.
Here are some outputs I get when logging out to the console:

```
console.log($window);                   // the Window object as expected
console.log($scope.$eval('$window'));   // undefined
console.log($scope.$eval('1+1'));       // 2
console.log($scope.$eval('scopeVar'));  // 'abc'
```

The controller has `$window` as a dependency. I can access scope variables and other services from expressions but not `$window`, so `$scope.$eval($window.alert())` doesn't work either.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you landed here from Angular 2+ land, a quick hack (if you already have a [template variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) `#someElem` lying around) would be to `someElem?.innerElement?.nativeElement?.ownerDocument.defaultView` (`?` for safety) - which resolves to the underlying `Window`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$scope.$eval` evaluates against the `$scope`, so your evaluation will work only if you assign $window service to scope member:

```
$scope.$window = $window;  
console.log($scope.$eval('$window'));
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but it seems newer versions of AngularJS (I'm on 1.2.4) doesn't allow accessing the window object from expressions due to security reasons and you get this [error](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse:isecwindow?p0=$window.alert() if you try. Well, I can't say the documentation is very consistent then... I'll just wrap the alert call in a controller function and use that from expressions.

Comment: Great, get out of my way, Angular! At this point you could just do `$scope.window = window;` yeah you'd lose mockability but honestly at this point I'm just glad to bypass Angular and mockability is not something we'd need very soon.