# Semicolon in AngularJS expression

Tags: angularjs

I want to have several things into one AngularJS expression but when use semicolon - ";" 
expression not working.

```
data-ng-click="secondTerm.keyphrase.selected=!secondTerm.keyphrase.selected; alert(1)"
```

How I can solve this problem?

Best regards.

Edit:

```
data-ng-click="secondTerm.keyphrase.selected=!secondTerm.keyphrase.selected;$window.alert(1)"
```

also don't work. Using of alert is just an example. I want to call other function after

```
secondTerm.keyphrase.selected=!secondTerm.keyphrase.selected
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing the window from Angular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998330/accessing-the-window-from-angular-expression)

Comment: `this` in an AngularJS expression is a `$scope`. `alert` is defined on `window`, it's not global. Read the duplicate question and answer.

Comment: data-ng-click="secondTerm.keyphrase.selected=!secondTerm.keyphrase.selected;$window.alert(1)" also don't work. alert(1) was only example. I just want to call other function instead alert.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you did not read the answer carefully: `$scope.$window = $window;`.

Comment: I want to call other function. I already write that alert is just an example.

Comment: chaining expression with semicolon between them should work. but I advise against it. you should call a function in your controller that will call all the functions you want to trigger.

Comment: Then something else is wrong in your code that you have not yet shown us. This kind of errors are easily spotted using the built in console and debugger in most modern browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply wrap them in a function for a best practice:

```
$scope.myFunc = function(){
    secondTerm.keyphrase.selected=!secondTerm.keyphrase.selected;
    $window.alert(1);
}

data-ng-click="myFunc()"
```

Comment: Hi Amir - in your `$scope.myFunc`, could we consider this a function expression and therefor put a semicolon after the closing `}`, so that it looks like `};`? I'm curious if this breaks the Angularjs app or makes no difference.

Comment: @KyleVassella - It's not mandatory but it's recommended. Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834642/why-should-i-use-a-semicolon-after-every-function-in-javascript